# Can I find a central list of all GAS files?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

When I go to script.google.com in order to get a list of all my scripts, I am redirected to [this link](https://script.google.com/d/1zkL9Tk7ydfdo5zn-Tea55rs66bYEVVStUAjMCKKisKWi4BfglolgHp3J/edit?splash=yes)

I am not looking to create a new script.

I have a script already created, but I can't get access to it, because when I go to script.google.com it redirects to a page to create a new script. Where can I find the script files that are already created?

Comment: In order to go directly to a specific script, there must be a file ID in the URL.  If your script is bound to a Sheet, Doc or Form, there is no central location to list all of your Apps Script projects.  Although, it should be listed in your settings of scripts that you have granted permissions to.  If the script is "Stand Alone", then it is listed in your Google Drive.  If the script is bound to document, the URL will be in the form of:  `https://script.google.com/macros/d/The_File_ID_Here/edit`  If it's stand alone, then `macros` is missing.

Comment: so complicated anyway

Answer (score 0):

The most central location for all files that you create in the Google environment is the Google Drive. When you are in the Drive, you will have access to *all* folders and files that you have created or that others have shared with you.

There is not a central location to find *only* the script files, especially if they are linked to Google Sheets or Google Forms. There *are* central locations to find only your documents (Google Docs) and only your sheets, or Forms, or sites. These can be accessed in the top right corner of your browser when you are logged into your Google account; it looks like a 3x3 square of squares.

If you have created scripts that are linked to Docs, Sheets, or Forms, you will need to access that file and go to the script editor to edit the file.

Comment: @MasterGrander "There is not a central location to find only the script files, especially if they are linked to Google Sheets or Google Forms." 

The problem is that somehow I've created a Script that runs dayly, and picks data from various similar datasheets. And I totaly can't remember wich one of spreadsheets I've used to attach that script. 

It continues to run dayly, but I need to do some edits. I've looked through bunch of my sheets, by hadn't find anything yet. 

So I'm asking if there is a solutions available. Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no simple way to fix that. This is purely a personal problem with organization and labeling. I suggest in the future to document your own work or have the process create a log elsewhere that you can reference what is being executed and when. This could look like an email notification, a running Google Doc log or simply having better management of your Google Drive work.

Comment: tell me more about that Google Log.

Comment: and where I should save log for logs? if they miss?